# NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier "win10-x64" is not recognized

Tags: .net, maui

When building a .NET MAUI app on Windows using .NET v8.0.100-rc.1.23455.8, I get the following error:

> NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier "win10-x64" is not recognized

On the [.NET SDK error list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/), there isn't much information about this error or how to solve it:

> NETSDK1083    The specified RuntimeIdentifier '{0}' is not recognized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Explanation

Long story short, it's a signing problem in this release of .NET 8 RC that is preventing .NET MAUI  v8.0.0-rc.1.9171 from installing automatically. You can find more information about the error here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17330.

### Work Around

To work around the signing problem, execute the following command in the Terminal:

##### Windows

```bash
dotnet workload install maui --skip-sign-check --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

##### macOS

```bash
sudo dotnet workload install maui --skip-sign-check --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Comment: I shouldn't have blindly run this command on my WPF project... It has installed dozens of MAUI packages and hasn't resolved the issue...

Comment: This was required for a brand freshly installed vs2022, .net 8, .net maui project

Comment: I tried this workaround but it is not working

Comment: So I was trying MAUI and couldn't get it to work. So I'm back to tinkering in an older WINUI3 project and I'm getting THIS error in VS?

Answer (score 8):

This occurs because the RID that you used (win10-x64) has been removed as Microsoft has reduced the number of RIDs.

Their reasoning;

> The RID graph was costly to maintain and understand, requiring .NET itself to be distro-aware in a fragile manner. The .NET team and the community spend a non-trivial amount of time updating the graph and backporting such updates to previous releases. The long-term goal is to stop updating the RID graph, stop reading it, and eventually remove it. This breaking change is a step towards that goal.

From this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#windows-rids) you can see that you now need to use win-x64.

More detail at;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/rid-graph

Answer (score 4):

This is [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/rid-graph) of the breaking changes introduced with .Net v8 RC1. It was introduced, since "RID graph was costly to maintain", and to remove the need for the ".NET to be distro-aware in a fragile manner".

In order to resolve the error, replace old RIDs with new RIDs given in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) in below mentioned files' `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` tag:

- `My Project\Properties\PublishProfiles\<distro>-<arch>.pubxml` (Don't change the file name)
- Project file `My Project.csproj` (Right click on project name in Solution Explorer and click 'Edit Project File')

Comment: The MAUI right click publish tooling still only has the old RID options. As of VS 2022 17.9.3