# RuntimeIdentifier is not recognized using .NET 8

Tags: .net, xaml, csproj, winui-3, .net-8.0

I would like to create a new WinUI 3 desktop application using .NET 8. After I initialze the project in Visual Studio, the project is on .NET 6. I change the .csproj file's TargetFramework from `net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0` to `net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0`, but this error pops up. How can I solve this issuewith .NET 8?

The errors:

```
NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier "win10-x86" is not recognized
NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier "win10-x64" is not recognized
NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier "win10-arm64" is not recognized
```

My `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
  <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
  <RootNamespace>SudokuEngineApp</RootNamespace>
  <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
  <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
  <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have tried with .NET 7 and it worked:

`<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>`

With .NET 8 it doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier "win10-x64" is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099837/netsdk1083-the-specified-runtimeidentifier-win10-x64-is-not-recognized). Specifically, see [the answer from Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77544154/592958)

Comment: I saw that, but not help me. I had to search for the answer and I found it.

Comment: So the bit in the linked answer _"you can see that you now need to use win-x64."_ didn't help even though that's exactly what you stated in your answer? Don't just look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after a bit of searching, I found the solution, that works for me.

The [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/rid-graph) says:

> Use portable RIDs, for example, `linux-<arch>`, `linux-musl-<arch>`, `osx-<arch>`, and `win-<arch>`.

So I changed the `RuntimeIdentifiers` and the `PublishProfile`.

The "10" had to be removed. Like `win10-x64` to `win-x64`.

My modified `.csproj` is the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
  <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
  <RootNamespace>SudokuEngineApp</RootNamespace>
  <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
  <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
  <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE WindowsAppSDK v1.4.4**

The workaround `UseRidGraph` is no longer needed from [WindowsAppSDKv1.4.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#version-144-14231219000:%7E:text=Updated%20Windows%20App%20SDK%20support%20for%20.NET%208%20RID%2Dspecific%20asset%20handling.).

---

Try these steps to upgrade to .NET 8:

1. Download and install the [.NET 8 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0).
2. Edit the *.csproj file.

   - `TargetFramework`: net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0
   - `RuntimeIdentifiers`: win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64
   - `PublishProfile`: win-$(Platform).pubxml
   - <s>Ad `UseRidGraph` and set it to `true`.</s>

   For example:

   ```xml
   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
     <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
     <RootNamespace>WinUI3App</RootNamespace>
     <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
     <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
     <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
     <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
     <!-- No longer needed from WindowsAppSDK v1.4.4.
     <UseRidGraph>true</UseRidGraph>
     -->
     <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
     <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

These steps might be changed/improved in later versions of **WindowsAppSDK**. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#version-142-14231008000:%7E:text=There%20was%20a,x86%3C/RuntimeIdentifier%3E) from the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

For me the .csproj files were already set to win-x64

I am using WinUI and in the Visual Studio Properties folder I have a file win10-x64.pubxml, I changed the runtime Id in here and it works a treat.

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```