# Visual Studio - Upgrading Project from .NET 6 to .NET 8

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0, winui-3, .net-8.0

I am trying to upgrade my **WinUI 3** project from **NET 6** to **NET 8** in **Visual Studio 2022**. I changed the target framework to net8.0 as many tutorials suggest but I get the following error:

> Error  MSB4086 A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)" that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition "'$(TargetPlatformMinVersion)' < '10.0.17200.0'".

Also is there a way to update the default Visual Studio templates so that they use NET 8 by default instead of NET 6?

**My project file code:**

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <RootNamespace>App12</RootNamespace>
  <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
  <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
  <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Have you installed latest version of Visual Studio?

Comment: You're missing some attributes, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557518/runtimeidentifier-is-not-recognized-using-net-8 and replace "win10-" by "win-"

Comment: Thanks for that Simon, removing the "10" from the end of the win part did the trick as well as adding back <TargetPlatformMinVersion> which I had deleted trying to fix the error.

Comment: Could you please mark answer for completion of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below solved my problem.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
  <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
  <RootNamespace>App12</RootNamespace>
  <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
  <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
  <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
</PropertyGroup>
```