# Blazor MAUI error while publishing -> The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-x86' is not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have a Blazor MAUI project with a ClassLibrary:

[image: screenshow-projects]

I want to publish this project via Publish -> Build Selection (Planning is selected). I use Sideloading (automatic updates: off). Publishing profile is MSIX-win10-x86.pubxml. Console returns an error:

`The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-x86' is not recognized.`

I built multiple versions in the past days, but since today I get this error. Maybe because I added the PlanningClassLibrary?

I googled en tried many things, installed multiple things from microsoft. Tried dotnet workload update / dotnet workload install maui... Don't get it back to work.

Anyone any tips?

Comment: Error says `See https://aka.ms/netsdk1083 for more information.` Not getting any further with this info...

Comment: Read the Recommended Action section of the page you linked, it says exactly what you need to do

Comment: @MateusZampol Any tips / example on how to use portable RIDs?

Comment: You could try 'win-x86'

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77099838/17455524)?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT yes, I tried that

Comment: Did you try to add `<UseRidGraph>true</UseRidGraph>` in the scproj?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT where to add `<UseRidGraph>true</UseRidGraph>`? Which file, between which lines?

Comment: In the csproj file(double click your solution project and you will see it).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes I tried. Double click on Planning. Then within `<Project>` and `<PropertyGroup>` I added `<UseRidGraph>true</UseRidGraph>`. This did not fix the problem

Comment: When I execute `dotnet publish Planning -r win-x86 -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0` I get an error `Packaged .NET applications with an app host exe cannot be ProcessorArchitecture neutral. Please specify a RuntimeIdentifier or a Platform other than AnyCPU.` while I have `<UseRidGraph>true</UseRidGraph>` in the Project csproj

Comment: Did you try to [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder?view=net-maui-8.0)? And it appears a known issue on the github: [dotnet publish fails on .NET SDK 8.0.100](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/37118).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT still not solved. `The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-x64' is not recognized. See https://aka.ms/netsdk1083 for more information.` error while publishing for win10-x64

Comment: Did you mean that publishing it with the Visual Studio met the same error? You can follow up the issue on the github.